# User ID and GDPR

Tags: gdpr, google

Is the user ID compliant with GDPR?
Imagine that a company starts associating a userID when you create an account on the website.

Just the company will be able to associate the userID with a specific person, meaning, it is just a PII for the company, because I will be able to know that specific userID belongs to the user x.

When sending this info to the Google Analytics, Google will never know to whom that userID belongs, so the user is not identifiable by Google.

Is this legal to do? Associate user ID to the users that create an account on the website?

I'm sorry if I was not clear.

Thank you

Comment: Please look at [tag:gdpr] - this is not the first question in that area.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GDPR - is user social ID personal data](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/32372/gdpr-is-user-social-id-personal-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Imagine that a company starts associating a userID when you create an account on the website

As soon as you attach *any* other personal data to that identifer, like for example an email address to sign up, or a name, then it is personal data.

It is exactly the same as a license plate, IP address or social security number. It identifies a person.

The fact that only a select few can access this data and actually draw a connection to a person does not matter. *Someone* can. That is all that's needed.

Comment: So we should not be able to know, for instance, the path that a specific user does on my website? that's it? 

Even though I have access to personal data that a user gives us when creating an account, I should not be able to know more than that? For examples: What websites that user is visiting, what path they are doing? Even if that info stays inside the company?

Comment: @PTaq GDPR does not forbid processing personal data. GDPR says you must have a 'lawful basis' for processing personal data.

Comment: in most cases: you have no legal basis to know anything beyond your own website.

Comment: Trish and Lag Yes, we are not forbidden. But are we allowed to identify every single user that navigates on our website? knows everything they search and all events they do? Even though only people inside the company knows that userID belongs to the user x? 
Marketing purpuses it's a lawful reason?
Thank you

Comment: @PTaq "Are you allowed to do X?" - yes, if you have a lawful basis for it. If yours are real circumstances then you ought to invest in proper legal advice. But you should review in particular Article 5 (the principles) and Article 6 (the lawful bases).

Comment: "Marketing Purposes" are *not* a lawful basis. However, *consent* is, so just tell the user in your terms of service that you track them, tell them that you will give their data to third parties like Google Analytics, *and have them explicitely agree to that* and you are perfectly fine.

Comment: "Any" information is too broad, there are some items that do not id the individual and would not be considered PII

Comment: @TigerGuy but you did read the full sentence right? The one that reads "any other **personal data**"?

Comment: @nvoigt that's a bit circular, "if it's personal data then it's personal data."

Comment: @TigerGuy no, if it can be used to identify personal data, it becomes Personal Identifiable Information.

Comment: @TigerGuy personal data can be contextual “Caucasian male, 30-40 years old, solid build, 1.7-1.8m tall, short black hair” is not PII because it describes a lot of people. But if we add “wanted in connection with an armed robbery in X place on Y date” it now is PII because it now describes a specific person - the suspected robber.